# The function NavTo works but let the previous view displayed in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

### Environement

Framework : SAPUI5 V 1.38.39
IDE: WebIDE

### Issue

I am using router.navTo(viewName) to navigate between my view, usually, it works fine but in my current project router.navTo(viewName) adds the view to the current one instead of replacing it.

### Some coding

in the current project to keep the header and footer without reloading them, I root from my Page control, so in manifest.json:

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "my.namespace.view",
        "controlId": "mainPage",
        "controlAggregation": "content",
        "async": true,
        "clearControlAggregation": true
    },
    [...]
```

In my "control view" :

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" controllerName="my.namespace.controller.TrackView">
    <Shell appWidthLimited="false">
        <App backgroundColor="white">
            <pages>
                <Page id="mainPage" class="pageLayout" showSubHeader="{user>/connected}">
                    <customHeader>
                        <OverflowToolbar class="customHeader">
                            <VBox class="centeringPage" id="idBoxHeader">
                                <core:Fragment fragmentName="my.namespace.view.fragment.Header" type="XML"/>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox id="blueBar" width="100%"/>
                        </OverflowToolbar>
                    </customHeader>
                    <subHeader>
                        <OverflowToolbar>
                            <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBarNoIcons" expanded="{device>/noPhone}" expandable="false" select="handleIconTabBarSelect"
                                    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" selectedKey="{user>/navStep}">
                                    <items>
                                        <IconTabFilter text="{i18n>nSearch}" enabled="{user>/searchStep}" id="idIconSearch"></IconTabFilter>
                                        <IconTabFilter text="{i18n>result}" enabled="{user>/resultStep}" id="idIconResult"></IconTabFilter>
                                        <IconTabFilter text="{i18n>tileTracking}" enabled="{user>/trackingStep}" id="idIconTracking"></IconTabFilter>
                                    </items>
                                </IconTabBar>
                        </OverflowToolbar>  
                    </subHeader>
                    <content>
                        <!--here are the different views-->
                    </content>
                    <footer>
                        <OverflowToolbar class="customFooter">
                            <core:Fragment fragmentName="my.namespace.view.fragment.Footer" type="XML"/>
                        </OverflowToolbar>
                    </footer>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

And when I load the page everything is ok the "search view" is correctly displayed, however when I navTo the "result view" the "result view" appends to the "search view" instead of replacing it
I use NavTo as follow in the controller :

```
var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
router.navTo("trackingResult", null, true);
```

Comment: Try checking if the problem exists on any newer UI5 versions like 1.71.26 or 1.60.32.

Comment: @GregMalewski it doesn't with newer version but the version cannot be changed at the moment

Comment: Does removing `clearControlAggregation` help? That attribute shouldn't be used anyway since it's meant to be used only for legacy apps that use `sap.ui.ux3.Shell` somewhere.